# Form values not updating using different for loops + Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, for-loop, html.beginform

I am currently using `Html.BeginForm("test", testForm", FormMethod.Post)` in order to update the values from my existing page.

I have more than 2 for-loops which allow to display the column name and the corresponding column value:

```
@for (var ctr = 1; ctr <= 5; ctr++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[ctr].id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[ctr].name)
        <td>@Model[ctr].name</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[ctr].value, new { @class = "span6" })</td>
    </tr>
 }
```

and

```
@for (var ctr = 7; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[ctr].id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[ctr].name)
        <td>@Model[ctr].name</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[ctr].value, new { @class = "span6" })</td>
    </tr>
 }
```

I also have a 'fixed' line item, both with column name and its value:

```
<tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[11].id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[11].name)
    <td>@Model[11].name</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[11].value, new { @class = "span6" })</td>
</tr>
```

When I clicked the submit button, only the 'fixed' line item was being updated. The line items with inside the for-loops were not updating.

Any suggestions how to fix these?

Comment: Is it possible that all elements will have the same name, and thus only the last element with that name is posted? Check your html source.

Comment: Please post your controller side code. so if you do something wrong then we can help you.